# How to show the error message in modal popup header in Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

How to show error message in header section in Bootstrap 5

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Add Email Group</h5>
    <div class="error">Invalid data, Please contact your administrator</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.error{
flex-wrap: wrap;
color:#ff0000;
}
```

**Expected Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions, very simple, you can add the tag span inside the title.

```
<h5 class="modal-title">Add Email Group<br><span style="color:red;font-size:12px;">Invalid data, Please contact your administrator</span></h5>
```

Comment: You should avoid adding things such as error messages in a title tag

Comment: In fact, I said it is the simplest way